# ssh: connect to host 192.168.56.3 port 4219: Can't assign requested address

Tags: command-line, ssh, virtualbox

I am using Ubuntu on a VM and I'm trying to connect to it in ssh (from a Mac).

Version:

[Release](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bcdB.png)

This is the command:

```
ssh -vvv -p 4219 sopi@192.168.56.3
```

This is the output:

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "192.168.56.3" port 4219
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.56.3 [192.168.56.3] port 4219.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.56.3 port 4219: Can't assign requested address
ssh: connect to host 192.168.56.3 port 4219: Can't assign requested address
```

Yes, I have installed ssh on the VM and yes it is running. This is how I checked:

```
 service ssh status
```

Yes, I have changed the sshd_config file to listed to port 4219

When I check if the port is actively in LISTENING I get this:

command:

```
sudo netstat -anp | grep -w LISTEN
```

output:

[output of command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8vMa.png)

Comment: Is that port forwarded in the VM host's firewall?

Comment: @TheMATEMan in all honesty I don't know. How would I check it? All I did with port forwarding is through VirtualBox. In 'network settings -> NAT -> advanced -> port forwarding

Comment: That is where you should be able to forward the 4219 port. You may also have to forward that port on your network, which should be in your router settings. Just curious, why are you trying to use port 4219 for ssh?

Comment: @TheMATEMan it's just a random one. The problem is that I have no access to the router. This is part of a exercise that I'm working on. An I'm the only one to have this trouble amongst my peers. I'm kinda lost at the moment...

Comment: @TheMATEMan This is the tutorial i'm following: https://github.com/acuD1/roger-skyline-1. You can see the prerequisites and then go in the tutorial.txt. I got stuck on 'setup Openssh'

Comment: I'm not sure how else to help. If that port if forwarded in virtulbox, I can't think of anything else. Maybe something on the network already uses that port? Try repeating your steps with a different port, perhaps a higher number port. I don't know what else you could do at this point.

Comment: A better way to setup ssh is to select the option to install it when you install Ubuntu, then change the ssh_config file to setup keys and use the port after the install.